# How to send dynamic metrics from MQTT to Prometheus?

Tags: apache-spark, mqtt, prometheus, grafana

I am trying to send dynamic metrics from IoT devices in Apache Spark Plug format from MQTT to Prometheus, my current setup looks something like this:

MQTT -> MQTT2Prometheus -> Prometheus -> Graphana

My current setup only works for metrics that are pre-configured in the MQTT2Prometheus config and I can not find a way to send metrics dynamically without knowing the metric name beforehand.

Are there any other libraries that can do this or are there ways to make MQTT2Prometheus work with dynamic metrics?